# No sound on my Asus Transformer

Tags: audio, asus-eee-pad-transformer

I have two problems :

- my device was dropped to the ground (not by me) and the power button does not work anymore. I use the keyboard to wake up and suspend it.
- sometime, the sound does not work anymore, and I cannot reboot it to make it run again.

The device is not rooted (no reason), run Android 4.0, how can I handle it?

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> my device was dropped to the ground

and

> sometime, the sound does not work anymore

This would very much seem to boil down to a hardware problem. The only way to "handle" it is to repair the hardware. You can start with the [Asus repair page](http://support.asus.com/repair.aspx).

Comment: Looks like the link is dead.